# Understanding webapp2 routes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, webapp2

Lets suppose i have the following webapp2 route.

```
webapp2.Route('/api/users/register/verify/<user_id:\d+>/<signup_token:.+>', users.VerificationHandler, name='verification')
```

I know first part is the URL, then is the name of request handler, but i don't understand the purpose of name='verification'. Can someone please explain why name is used in webapp2 routes?

Moreover, what is the purpose of uri_for() function? why do we use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

programatically `webapp2` is class and `Route` was a function defined inside a class.

**webapp2** is nothing but a routing mechanism that extends the webapp model to provide additional features:

- **URI building:** the registered routes can be built when needed, avoiding hardcoded URIs in the app code and templates.
- **Keyword arguments:** handlers can receive keyword arguments from the matched URIs.
- **Nested routes:** routes can be extended to match more than the request path. We will see below a route class that can also match
  domains and subdomains.

**Eg:** `webapp2.Route('/api/users/register/verify/<user_id:\d+>/<signup_token:.+>', handler=HomeHandler, name='verification')`

from your example, `name='verification'`

it is alias for your url...

in your example,

your URL is : `'/api/users/register/verify/<user_id:\d+>/<signup_token:.+>'`
you cant able to remember it right, so name will help you to alias it with memorable one `verification`.

so your URL,  `/api/users/register/verify/<user_id:\d+>/<signup_token:.+>` = `verification`

**alias will translate into original url in runtime**

next, **uri_for()**

as i said, you assigned alias for your big URL.. so you knew shortest alias of it. if you want to retrieve URL from alias you can use this function,

```
print uri_for('verification')
```

will give you, `/api/users/register/verify/<user_id:\d+>/<signup_token:.+>`

Comment: so can we say "name" is used to make long URL short? and it is for the easy of developer only?

Comment: yes.. it wont make url . its like alias... it wont show in address bar.. it will translate in run time.. short URL will be assigned into long in backend.. python only knew that.. it will translate once you execute

Comment: Thanks for this well explained answer.!

Comment: The `name` variable is not just for shortening the url. If you have many redirects in your handlers and links in your templates to a url and then that url changes, then you'll have broken redirects and links that you'll need to fix. If those redirects and links point to the Route's `name` instead of the Route's url, then your redirects and links won't break when you change the url of the Route.